# Laravel : GuzzleHttp Client

Tags: php, guzzle6

I am using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"` and trying to github users using below code .

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users');
$query = $request->getQuery();
$query->set('since',135);
$response = $request->send();
$oResponse = json_decode($response->getBody(true));
```

But I am getting error 
`Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given`
But this method works on `"guzzle/guzzle": "^3.9",` I don't know where I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"` will get you Guzzle v6.1.1.  Methods and method signatures are not the same between v3.9 and v6.1.  So much so that `Client::createRequest()` does not exist within v6.1 and infact is caught by `Client::__call()` and then passed to `Client::request()` where you are obtaining your error because provided arguments to not match the signature for `Client::request()`.

More information on Guzzle 6 can be obtained from [Guzzle docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).

You will also find that your `$request->send()` will throw an error.  Guzzle 6 took Psr7 to heart and as such the Request / Response objects implement the Psr7 specification.

Comment: This is very good technical information that explains why the errors are encountered, but it doesn't offer insight into a quick resolution of the problem. Can you expand this answer?

Comment: Version mismatch.  Developing to one API, while another is what is actually on the system.